# Create new variable if second row of a column matches a value in r

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'd like to create a new variable `A_row_error` that puts 'TRUE' if `first_A_row = TRUE` and the message of the following row = ERROR (and FALSE if next row when `A_row_error = TRUE` is any other message). Note that the next row is determined by the timestamp, and must be in ascending order. The TRUE message for `A_row_error` must also be on the same row as when `first_A_row = TRUE` (see table below for desired output).

Sample dataset:

```
participant_id <- c("ps1", "ps1", "ps1", "ps1", "ps2", "ps2", "ps3", "ps3", "ps3", "ps3")
timestamp <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04)
event <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A")
first_A_row <- c("TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE")
message <- c("ACCEPTED", "ERROR", "DECLINED", "ACCEPTED", "HELLO", "BYE", "ACCEPTED", "BYE", "ERROR", "ACCEPTED")
data.frame(participant_id, timestamp, event, first_A_row, message)
```

Desired output:

| participant_id | timestamp | event | first_A_row | message | A_row_error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ps1 | 0.01 | A | TRUE | ACCEPTED | TRUE |
| ps1 | 0.02 | A | FALSE | ERROR | FALSE |
| ps1 | 0.03 | A | FALSE | DECLINED | FALSE |
| ps1 | 0.04 | B | FALSE | ACCEPTED | FALSE |
| ps2 | 0.01 | B | FALSE | HELLO | FALSE |
| ps2 | 0.02 | A | TRUE | BYE | FALSE |
| ps3 | 0.01 | A | TRUE | ACCEPTED | FALSE |
| ps3 | 0.02 | A | FALSE | BYE | FALSE |
| ps3 | 0.03 | B | FALSE | ERROR | FALSE |
| ps3 | 0.04 | A | FALSE | ACCEPTED | FALSE |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by 'participant_id' and use the `lead`  of 'message' to create the logical i.e. if the next value is 'ERROR' and the given row for 'first_A_row' is TRUE (the column `first_A_row` was created as character instead of logical - so it is converted with `as.logical`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(participant_id) %>%
   mutate(A_row_error = lead(message, default = last(message)) == 
        'ERROR' & as.logical(first_A_row)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   participant_id timestamp event first_A_row message  A_row_error
   <chr>              <dbl> <chr> <chr>       <chr>    <lgl>      
 1 ps1                 0.01 A     TRUE        ACCEPTED TRUE       
 2 ps1                 0.02 A     FALSE       ERROR    FALSE      
 3 ps1                 0.03 A     FALSE       DECLINED FALSE      
 4 ps1                 0.04 B     FALSE       ACCEPTED FALSE      
 5 ps2                 0.01 B     FALSE       HELLO    FALSE      
 6 ps2                 0.02 A     TRUE        BYE      FALSE      
 7 ps3                 0.01 A     TRUE        ACCEPTED FALSE      
 8 ps3                 0.02 A     FALSE       BYE      FALSE      
 9 ps3                 0.03 B     FALSE       ERROR    FALSE      
10 ps3                 0.04 A     FALSE       ACCEPTED FALSE
```

Comment: thanks again! I didn't know about default. Is that the part that puts the message on the same row (#1)?

Comment: I didn't get your comment.

Comment: Is this part 'default = last(message))' what ensures that TRUE under A_row_error appears on the first row (same row as TRUE under first_A_row)?

Comment: @elmolibra if we don't specify the default, it will be `NA` and then the `==` will return `NA` for that row because missing value with comparison operators return NA